# Open an Image from Application Persistence Data Path using Unity -Windows Phone 10

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, windows-10-mobile

Can anyone tell me how can I open an image from application persistance data path or how can I save directly into Pictures in Windows Phone using Unity?
Thank you!

Comment: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/858245/save-and-load-texture-with-systemio-filestream.html

Comment: To open a file from your storage using unity on windows use [this](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/54715).